# C++ does it lead to double free when destroy element in allocator<string>?

Tags: c++, std, allocator

C++ Allocator. I know that String will allocate a block buffer with `new` at inner implement, and free it(call delete[]) within Destructor.

My question is that whether it will be free double when use `allocator<string>`?

1. first free at string destructor.
2. second deallocate buffer points to string has been free.

Additionally, whether does the buffer address of string and `allocate(n)` have same region?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const int cnt = 10;
    allocator<string> alloc;
    auto p = alloc.allocate(cnt);

    alloc.construct(p);
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
    {
        cout << p+i << endl; // print buffer address
    }

    alloc.destroy(p); // will it free buffer of string?

    alloc.deallocate(p, cnt); // will it free buffer of string again?

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write something like this:

```
Foo *foo = new Foo();
```

two things happen:

1. Some heap space is allocated for the `Foo` object.
2. The `Foo()` constructor is invoked, with `this` pointing to the newly-allocated space.

Later, you delete the `Foo` object:

```
delete foo;
```

and two more things happen:

1. The destructor `~Foo()` is invoked.
2. The memory allocated for the Foo instance is released back to the heap.

The `std::allocator` class just lets you perform each of these four steps manually.

If you have an `allocator<string> alloc` and you call `alloc.allocate` and then `alloc.construct`, that's just the same as doing `new string()`. And when you call `alloc.destroy` and then `alloc.deallocate`, that's just the same as deleting the `string` pointer.

So no, there won't be any extra frees going on. The call to `destroy` causes the `string` to release whatever memory it allocated for its buffer, and then the call to `deallocate` releases the memory that was used for the `string` object itself.

I didn't completely understand your question about the region. The memory allocated to store the `string` instance, and the memory that the `string` allocates for its buffer, are unrelated.

Answer (score 6):

### Let's start with `delete`

When you `delete` an object there are two things that happen:

1. the destructor of that's object is called
2. the memory allocated for this object with `new` is being released back to the heap

### `placement new` and `delete`

You can use placement `new` syntax for constructing an object on an existing memory buffer:

```
const char* charString = "Hello, World";
// allocate the required memory
void *mem = ::operator new(sizeof(Buffer) + strlen(charString) + 1);
// construct a "Buffer" object on an existing memory block
Buffer* buf = new(mem) Buffer(strlen(charString));

// ...

// destruct the "Buffer" object without releasing the memory
buf->~Buffer();
// deallocate the memory
::operator delete(mem);
```

Of course for this example you could just use plain `new` and `delete` but it shows how you can separate the memory allocation from its construction and the destruction from the deallocation.

This technique is useful for example if you manage memory pool and the memory can be reclaimed back to the memory pool when the object is destructed rather than back to the heap.

### std::allocator

[`std::allocator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) gives you the above behavior - separation of memory allocation and deallocation from the object construction and destruction with the methods `allocate`, `construct`, `destroy` and `deallocate`.

```
allocator<string> alloc;
size_t n = 3;
auto p = alloc.allocate(n); // memory is allocated for n elements
alloc.construct(p);           // object is constructed on that memory

// ...

alloc.destroy(p);         // object is destructed
alloc.deallocate(p, n); // memory is deallocated
```

Note that `std::string` destructor would call `delete` on its internal allocation when the `string` object is destructed, but the memory occupied by the object itself is deallocated in above code only in the call to `alloc.deallocate`.

---

### `construct` and `destroy` being deprecated in C++17

C++17 declared the methods `construct` and `destroy` of `std::allocator` **deprecated** and C++20 made them **obsolete**. So, since C++17 you would have to either go back to `placement new`, or better (thanks @Evg for the comment) - use [std::allocator_traits::construct()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/construct) which has the benefit of being `constexpr` since C++20. For the destruction, call the destructor directly after deallocating the memory with the allocator:

```
allocator<string> alloc;
size_t n = 3;
auto p = alloc.allocate(n); // memory is allocated for n elements
// alloc.construct(p);        // deprecated in C++17, obsolete in C++20
// option a:
   // new(p) string; // construct the object with placement new
// option b, better - (potentially) constexpr since C++20:
std::allocator_traits<allocator<string>>::construct(alloc, p, "hello");

// ...

// alloc.destroy(p);      // deprecated in C++17, obsolete in C++20
p->~string(); // destruct the object by calling the destructor
alloc.deallocate(p, n); // memory is deallocated
```

[Code link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/158acb9698be353d)

---

### `construct_at` and `destroy_at` *

* since C++20 and C++17, respectively.

With [`construct_at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/construct_at) and [`destroy_at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy_at) the code above can be written as:

```
allocator<string> alloc;
size_t n = 3;
auto p = alloc.allocate(n); // memory is allocated for n elements
std::construct_at(p, "hello"); // added in C++20

// ...

std::destroy_at(p); // destruct the object - added in C++17
alloc.deallocate(p, n); // memory is deallocated
```

This one is the simplest, if you are in C++20 I'd recommend this option.

[Code link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebd3cad6e5046b07)

---

Last note: there is also a thing called `placement delete` it is not called directly by the programmer but only from `placement new` if the constructor of the object throws an exception. So don't get confused with that. The way to destruct an object in place without releasing the memory occupied by the object itself is by calling its destructor directly as shown above (or if you use std::allocator prior to C++17, by calling the allocator destroy method).

Last and final note: if you wonder why `deallocate` require a size? see: [why does std::allocator::deallocate require a size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38771551/why-does-stdallocatordeallocate-require-a-size)

Comment: +1 This is a very detailed answer. But i had to search a bit and understand two things before i could grasp the answer: 1) "operator new()" is different than "new" ("operator new" is a function that just allocates memory)  AND 2) "placement new" is different than "new". ("placement new" just constructs an object in a given place)

Comment: Since C++17, `std::allocator_traits` should be used, not placement `new`. In C++20, placement `new` can't be used in `constexpr` context, whereas [`std::allocator_traits::construct()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/construct) can.

Comment: @Evg good point, embedded into the answer with a proper credit note.

Answer (score 1):

You may inherit `std::string` to add some print statements, to get a better understanding (Or you need to debug and step into the STL container and functions)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MyString : public string {
    public:
    MyString() = default;
    ~MyString() { cout << "destructor of MyString:" << this << endl; }
};
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const int cnt = 10;
    allocator<MyString> alloc;
    auto p = alloc.allocate(cnt);

    alloc.construct(p);
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
    {
        cout << p+i << endl; // print buffer address
    }

    alloc.destroy(p); // will it free buffer of string?

    cout << "alloctor destrory called" << endl;

    alloc.deallocate(p, cnt); // will it free buffer of string again?

    return 0;
}
```

Execute it here:

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13302c7f0c4db07b