# Double free in c++ destructor

Tags: c++, memory, free

I'm trying to implement a linked list in C++. The list contains a pointer to a node type allocated on the heap

The code is as follow:

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class node {
public:
    node(T v) : value(v) {}
    
    ~node() = default;

    T value;
    node *next;
};

template<typename T, class Allocator = std::allocator<node<T>>>
class linked_list {
private:
    node<T>* head;
    Allocator alloc;

public:
    linked_list() : head(nullptr) {}

    ~linked_list() {
        for (auto start = head; start != nullptr; start = start->next) {
            start->~node();
            alloc.deallocate(start, 1);
        }
    }

    void push_back(T value) {
        node<T> *new_node = alloc.allocate(1); 
        new (new_node) node<T>(value);

        if (head == nullptr) {
            head = new_node;
            return;    
        }

        head->next = new_node;
        head = new_node;
    }
};
```

In main.cpp:

```
#include "linked_list.hpp"

int main() {
    linked_list<int> a;

    a.push_back(4);
    a.push_back(5);


    return 0;
}
```

When I ran it I got double free detected in cache T2.
What did I do wrong with the destructor ?

Comment: This `start->~node();` is very strange.  And why use placement new here `new (new_node) node<T>(value);` ?  I don't think placement new / delete are required in this program.

Comment: Even compiler finds error: https://godbolt.org/z/Kevjhenvo

Comment: The code violates the rule of 3 / 5 /0: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: Could you elaborate ?

Comment: *I'm trying to implement a linked list in C++* -- Why did you get into the weeds of using `placement-new`?  Why not simply use `new`, and then graduate to smart pointers from there?

Comment: Again compiler explains what is the issue: after one iteration when object was deleted, `start->next` (in for statement) is access to go to next element what is UB!

Comment: @Kain This for loop         for (auto start = head; start != nullptr; start = start->next) {
            start->~node();
            alloc.deallocate(start, 1);
        } invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I read that construct and destroy is deprecated in C++17 here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59539057/c-does-it-lead-to-double-free-when-destroy-element-in-allocatorstring

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Could you explain to me why does it do that ?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I wonder if the point was to allow a different allocator to be substituted in instead of the default one.   This was the syntax used in C++98

Comment: When you insert a new node, it's `next` pointer is left uninitialized. How should the condition `start != nullptr` work? Also, `head->next = new_node; head = new_node;` doesn't make sense to me. Where does `head->next` point to after those assignments?

Comment: `start = start->next` since `start` was already destructed, use-after-destruction is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: Problem is not related to rule 3/5/0 since nothing gets copied or assigned. Problem is use after free!

Comment: The Rule of Three doesn't even **remotely** apply here.

Comment: @Eljay I figured it out, thanks.

Comment: *construct and destroy is deprecated in C++17* - That's true, but the answer you're referring to is wrong. The correct way is to go through `std::allocator_traits`, which has a static member function `construct()`. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/construct). This is also true for `allocate()`.

Comment: Note, your `node`s only have a pointer to the next element, and when you push element to list, you are updating the `head` pointer to the new element, which means you don't have a way to get back to the first element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common newbie error.  You modified your loop control variable.

```
for (auto start = head; start != nullptr; start = start->next)
{
     start->~node();
     alloc.deallocate(start, 1);
}
```

You modified `start` (deleting the memory) in the for loop's body and then tried to dereference the pointer you just deleted in its continuation expression. [BOOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)!  You are fortunate that the runtime library was smart enough to catch this and give you the "double free" error rather than, say, launch a nuclear missile.

This is one place a while loop is better than a for loop.

```
while (head)
{
   auto to_del = head;
   head = head->next; 
   to_del ->~node();
   alloc.deallocate(to_del, 1);
}
```

I've left out a lot of commentary about your antiquated techniques because they don't relate to the problem you're having, but if you really want to substitute in a different kind of allocator you should look into using `allocator_traits` for allocation, construction, destruction, and deallocation of your elements.

There are other problems, such as `push_back` being completely wrong as to where it inserts the new node.  Replacing `head->next = new_node;` with `new_node->next = head;` will at least keep your program from orphaning all of the new nodes.

Comment: This alone won't fix the code because `push_back()` implementation is also broken.

Comment: @Evg Agreed.  I made a little edit but I don't want to get into the weeds.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/coz5nvrY8